# Using a multiplexer for multiple UART connections to ESP32

Tags: uart, multiplexer, esp32

I have a single channel 2:1 MUX ([TMUX7219 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmux7219.pdf)) and I'd like the module to switch channels whenever I connect a USB to my board.  The USB's 5V+ line will connect to the SEL pin and EN will always be 5V.

The table below specifies that when SEL pin is driven high (1.8V-VDD) S2 is connected to the drain, but I am wondering what will happen if SEL is not connected to anything?  This will happen when I unplug the USB and the VDD line, will S1 be connected to the drain or will neither S1 or S2 be connected?

My goal is to have S1 connected to drain when a USB is not connected to the board.

Also I am assuming VSS is equal to GND in this situation?
[image: MUX]
[image: Table]

This is what my circuit currently looks like:
[image: mux circuit]

**Edit:**
So 2 months later I built the PCB connected the micro-USB to the board and things are not working and based on my observations I suspect it is likely a problem with the multiplexer.  Here are some voltage readings and observations that may help.
When I plug in the micro-USB I see:
5V on Vdd, EN, and SEL, and 5V continuous net.
3.3V on S2 and Drain.
0.6V on S1.

But I get a strange error from Windows saying that USB device not recognized and I cannot find a port in Arduino IDE.  But if I plug in another ESP board that I have purchased from a manufacturer no problem at all.  I am clueless at this point.

[image: firmware upload circuit]

Comment: This is what pullup and pulldown resistors exist for: you can set default state when nothing is connected. If the line isn't connected to anything at all without any resistors, it will "float", meaning it won't have fixed voltage and it can randomly change states or even oscillate, which is unlikely to be the desired behavior. All lines must have known values at all times (unless you have specific reason not to). As pointed out below, looks like your chip has integrated resistors for that, but you can always you external too (or whenever there are no internal ones)

Answer (score 2):

This device has internal pull resistors on the EN and SEL inputs. See section 8.4 pf the datasheet. These resistors will determine what happens when the EN and SEL inputs are not connected to anything. Of course, you can also add resistors to your board.

Comment: how can I use these resistors or external ones to make S1 pass to drain when SEL is not connected to USB 5V, I don't fully understand.

Comment: If you want SEL to be high when USB is not connected, add a resistor between SEL and VDD. If you want SEL to be low when USB is not connected, add a resistor between SEL and ground.

Comment: For the second alternative, SEL low when USB disconnected, if I chose a 1k resistor would the current flowing to ground be significant when usb is disconnected?  Reason I ask is I am operating off a battery.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to determine whether the current is "significant" in your application. When the USB is disconnected the maximum current through the resistor would be the maximum leakage current of the SEL pin, which is specified as \$1\,\mu\text{A}\$. When the USB is connected you will draw \$5\,\text{mA}\$ from the USB power source.

Answer (score 1):

Without my hands on it, I guess problem can be found somewhere else than the given circuitry itself. See if you like my observations.

1)TMUX7219 datasheet is missing information about logic input current, or my eyes just are missing it.

2)We can assume TMUX7219 operates with EN & SEL disconnected to route S1 to D, according to TMUX7219 datasheet "Table 5-1" & "Table 8-1". That means we can drop R302. According to the given drawings, it is okay to make R302 1K or even lower, since current comes from plugged USB_VDD, assuming USB_VDD goes no other places. If USB_VDD is connected somewhere else, check if that connection sources any current. In order to confirm that, USB_VDD can be measured with and without USB connected.

3)In the drawing, D304 & the net label "5V_Continuous" look strange. I would wonder if 5V_Continuous is always and continuous. The MUX needs power continuously. Is it diode OR and charging circuit?

4)I would check voltage status on MUX pins anyway, with and without USB connected. That may tell more story.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  From the datasheet we see "When the EN pin of the TMUX7219 is pulled high, one of the switches is closed based on the state of the SEL
pin. When the EN pin is pulled low, both of the switches are in an open state regardless of the state of the SEL
pin."  So statement 2 is incorrect.

Comment: I think I should have noted that 5V continuous net is powered by Vdd if the only source of power is the USB.  Otherwise power is routed from other sources, but at any point of time when the board is in use this net is at 5V.

Comment: Try AN oscilloscope or a DMM; Measure the voltage on each pin of the MUX, with/without USB plugged, write those down. If that tells no problem, then the issue is the serial data signal.